# How to batch rename in windows with python

Tags: python, windows-7, rename

I have a large list of file names that are illegal, I want to rename them with the '`ren`' command.  How can I execute '`ren`' in batch on windows 7 with python?

Comment: Call a batch file from python?

Comment: Carefully and with `os.rename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the python function, it will be easier to catch errors rather than relying on the `ren` command.

```
import os
os.rename(src, dst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't really want to use a [batch renaming utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)?

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

sts = os.system("mycmd" + " myarg")

or

sts = call("mycmd" + " myarg", shell=True)

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

example:

```
    import os
    os.system("rename.bat")
    #or use command "start" for start bat files
```